# dojo treeGrid aggregate not working after refreshing jsonStore

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

I have dojo treeGrid that shows totals for child items. Everything works fine. But if I replace/update store and refresh then aggregation doesn't work and all totals shown as NaN. What am I doing wrong?

```
var layout = [ 
    { cells: [ 
       [ {field: "userName", name: "Name"}, 
         {field: "childItems", 
           children: [ { field: "debit", name: "debit"},
                       { field: "credit", name: "credit"}  
                     ], 
                  aggregate: "sum" 
                  } 
                  ]] } ]

var jsonStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({ url: "<............>"});


var grid = new dojox.grid.TreeGrid({ 
    structure: layout, 
    store: jsonStore, 
    query: {type: 'year'}, 
    queryOptions: {deep: true},
    rowSelector: true, 
    openAtLevels: [false],
    autoWidth: true,
    autoHeight: true
    }, 
    dojo.byId("treeGrid"));

//replace store button
var button = dojo.query("[id$=':buttonReplace']")[0];
dojo.on(button,'click',
    function(e){ 
        grid.store.close();
        grid.store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({ url: "<... new store url...>"});    
        grid._refresh();
    }
);  

grid.startup();
dojo.connect(window, "onresize", grid, "resize");
```

Comment: Have you tried using `grid.setStore(<storeObject>)` or `grid.set('store', <storeObject>)`. Playing directly with dojo widget attributes is not recommended.

Comment: grid.setStore(<storeObject>) helps somehow. Now it shows 0 instead of NaN. But it breaks categorized structure of the tree. How do I properly refresh/reload it then?

Comment: Is there a `grid.refresh()` available? Can you use that instead of `grid._refresh()`?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: grid.refresh is not a function

Comment: Please refer to my comment on your other question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51127103/how-to-filter-dojo-categorized-treegrid#comment89314640_51127103).